# c programming scanf wired behavior

Tags: c, scanf

I copy the code from a book , it's a loop like blow,

```
for(;;)
{
    printf("enter a value");
    scanf("%lf",&value);
    tot al+=value;
    ++count;
    printf("do you want to enter another value?(N or Y):");
    scanf("%c",&answer);
    if(tolower(answer)=='n')
        break;
}
```

but it has some strange behavior, when I evaluate it ,it gives the out put

```
[tintin@tintin-laptop Documents]$ ./test 
this enter a value3
do you want to enter another value?(N or Y):enter a value
```

I checked it carefully and finally when I changed

```
scanf("%c",&answer);
```

with a space before %c which is

```
scanf(" %c",&answer);
```

it behaved normally like

```
[tintin@tintin-laptop Documents]$ ./test
this enter a value2
do you want to enter another value?(N or Y):y
enter a value3
do you want to enter another value?(N or Y):
```

why could this thing happen?

Comment: +1 for an OP who showed _code_, _input_ and _output_.  Unfortunately this is too rare.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are hit by the newline character left in the input stream.

The leading space in the format string will ensure scanf() ignores all whitespaces. Hence, the latter version works as expected.

You can find this information on the manual of **[scanf()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/scanf.html)**:

> A directive composed of one or more white-space characters shall be
>   executed by reading input until no more valid input can be read, or up
>   to the first byte which is not a white-space character, which remains
>   unread.